# Strange sound on Windows, like somone navigating between folders

Tags: windows

When I connect to the Internet I often hear a sound, like someone navigating between folders on my PC.

What does this sound mean? Did anyone come across this behavior?

Comment: Do you hear it any time you are connected (even if there is no browser or other program open, etc.)?

Comment: If only in a browser, all browsers or a specific one? Do you hear it only when clicking on a link?

Comment: If you mean that when you plug in the internet cable or turn on your wifi you get a "doo-dump" sound or two after several seconds, that's the system indicating that it's made a connection.  If instead you mean that sounds continue occurring once you're connected, I don't know.

Comment: I hope there is no **Ghost** in your machine. ;P

Comment: @avirk: But there is Ghostery in mine! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have heard this before on machines infected with spyware or malware.  The cause is the malware is attempting to load internet content, popups, or download other malware in the background in a hidden window.

To rule this out as the cause I would install and run a few anti-malware programs such as Spybot Search & Destroy, ComboFix, and HijackThis.